# Is it possible in Android to implement a recursive alarm or an alarm that overwrites itself?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I'm thinking of broadcasting an `Intent` from my `MainActivity` to be received by `SomeReceiver`, then register a new alarm somewhere in `onReceive()` which fires an `Intent` that `SomeReceiver` will again catch. Is that possible? How do I overwrite the old alarm with the new one and make sure the old one is killed or unregistered?

UPDATE: The `MainActivity` will not be open at all times and the Alarm will need to keep being fired nonetheless.

Comment: Reschedule you alarm in SomeReceiver. Easy.

Comment: How do I do that? Do I simply add a `AlarmManager.set()` call within the `onReceive()`? What about the one that was set before?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please convert your comment to an answer so I can select it and close this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First call of alarm is depends on your logic. For next alarm you should reschedule alarm in onreceive of receiver. You are right you need to call `set()`. Repeating time in not fixed? If yes then go ahead. U r on right track. But if repeating time is fixed, then you should use `setRepeating()`.